# Apache Sqoop import fails for MySQL when --where clause has column name with space

Tags: mysql, sqoop

Having trouble with sqoop import command when --where clause has column name with a space. Database is MySQL.

**MySQL table**

```
create table testsqoop(`x t` integer);

insert into testsqoop values(1);
insert into testsqoop values(2);
insert into testsqoop values(3);
insert into testsqoop values(4);
insert into testsqoop values(5);

select * from testsqoop where `x t` > 2;
+------+
| x t  |
+------+
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Sqoop Command**

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mytestdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&?user=test&password=test' --username test --password test --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --table testsqoop --target-dir /user/tmp/testsqoop -m 1 --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table default.test --hive-delims-replacement ' '  --outdir /tmp/ --direct --where "`x t` > 2"
```

**Error**

```
Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:277)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '> 2 ) AND ( 1=1 ) AND ( 1=1 )' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.executeQuery(DBRecordReader.java:111)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:235)
... 12 more
```

None of these seem to work - 
    --where "`x t` > 2"
    --where ""x t" > 2"
    --where "'x t' > 2"

Answer (score 1):

Try using brackets [] :

where [x t] > 2

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately. Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[x t] > 2 ) AND ( 1=1 ) AND ( 1=1 )' at line 1

Comment: Can you try using free form query instead of the --where option. LIke this :

Comment: --query 'select * from testsqoop where `x t` > 2 WHERE $CONDITIONS'

Comment: [x t] instead of x t. Cant figure out how to edit my comments :(

Comment: The following works with the free form query option, I am however trying to use the where option and that's where I see the issue. sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mytestdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&?user=test&password=test' --username test --password test --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --target-dir /user/tmp/testsqooq -m 1 --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-table default.test --hive-delims-replacement ' '  --outdir /tmp/ --direct --query "select * from testsqoop where \\`x t\\` > 2 AND \$CONDITIONS"